# How to call a method from controller when a button from form is pressed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The main problem is that a method from controller is not called when i press a button.
I have this in my Index view for MyController :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@* .... *@
<form action="DoSomethingAction" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="IdString" name="IdString" placeholder="Enter id"/>
    <input id="Submit1" name="Submit1" type="submit" value="DoSomething1" />
    <input id="Submit2" name="Submit2" type="submit" value="DoSomething2" />
</form>
@* ..... *@
}
```

In MyController I have DoSomethingAction method. I want to call this method and be able to see IdString when I press a button: DoSomething1 or DoSomething2.  This is DoSomethingAction method from controller:

```
 public ActionResult DoSomethingAction()
    {
        string id= Request.Form["IdString"];
        //string button=...

        // ...
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint for DoSomethingAction method, I observed that it's never called.
I tried to put [Httppost] attribute for this method, but it didn't solve my problem.

What am I doing wrong? 
After that, how can I see in DoSomethingAction method which button was pressed?

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html and not suported

Comment: Fix the invalid nested forms, accept the answer for that then come back with new question perhaps on new issue(s) that you have.  Try to keep questions to one question and you will likely get better response and progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a HTML form can not nest a HTML form. Please read https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

If you need multiple form you can define them as siblings.

Comment: I changed my code. I put the form under `@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ }`. The method is still not called and I receive an error: "Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /DoSomethingAction" . I guess now it's searching for a view with the name DoSomethingAction and that's not what I want...

Comment: It does't find the path in app. Make sure your routing are correct. If the views is not found ".cshtml is not found" will be shown.

Comment: I tried to add a new route  `           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DoSomethingAction",
                url: "My/DoSomethingAction",
                defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "DoSomethingAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); `  to RouteConfig. I am not really sure if it's correct. I suppose it's not because I receive the same error

Comment: @SomeoneNew try with adding {id} in url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `html.BeginForm` or  `type="Submit"`. Next thing to keep in mind, `html.BeginForm` is a post method, so if u want to use it, give an attribute over Action and if u don't state what `view` action should return, he will assume that view is of the same name as action, in ur case `DoSomethingAction`, that's why u get server error. Either make that view or state in `return View()` which view u want to return (Index or some other).